# Login into server causes podman containers to restarts

Tags: containers, systemd, podman

It seems that anytime I log into my homeserver, podman containers are restarting:

```
❯ ssh podman@192.168.1.116
podman@192.168.1.116's password:
Web console: https://homeserver.localdomain:9090/ or https://192.168.1.116:9090/

Register this system with Red Hat Insights: insights-client --register
Create an account or view all your systems at https://red.ht/insights-dashboard
Last login: Wed Nov 22 21:38:24 2023 from ::ffff:192.168.1.111
[podman@homeserver ~]$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                                 COMMAND               CREATED        STATUS                   PORTS                                                                                                                                             NAMES
6a4b5a1ca375  docker.io/louislam/uptime-kuma:latest                 node server/serve...  2 seconds ago  Up 3 seconds (starting)  0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp                                                                                                                            uptime-kuma
3b97cda03874  lscr.io/linuxserver/unifi-network-application:latest                        2 seconds ago  Up 2 seconds (starting)  0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8843->8843/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8880->8880/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3478->3478/udp, 0.0.0.0:10001->10001/udp  systemd-unifi_network_application
a6b35bd7ccd7  docker.io/pihole/pihole:latest                                              2 seconds ago  Up 3 seconds (starting)  0.0.0.0:53->53/udp, 0.0.0.0:53->53/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                                                                                        systemd-pihole
e45ca3fde4bf  docker.io/library/mongo:4.4.25                        mongod                2 seconds ago  Up 2 seconds (starting)  0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                                                                                                                          unifi_mongodb
```

The same happened yesterday at about 17:15 when I logged in via cockpit: all containers were created and restarted immediately after my login.

I'm using quadlet files to create systemd services and this is an example file:

```
[Unit]
Description=UniFi MongoDB
After=local-fs.target

[Container]
Image=docker.io/mongo:4.4.25
ContainerName=unifi_mongodb
Environment=MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
Secret=unifi_mongodb_root_password,type=env,target=MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
Network=unifi_network_application.network
Volume=unifi_mongodb_data:/data/db
PublishPort=27017:27017
HealthCmd=CMD-SHELL mongo --eval 'db.runCommand({ping:1})'
HealthInterval=30s
HealthRetries=2
HealthOnFailure=kill

[Service]
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target default.target
```

I'm not sure if the latter is misconfigured or I'm missing something else.

Comment: Which directory did you place your quadlet definitions in? Did it generate system services or user services?

Comment: quadlet files are in `/home/podman/.config/containers/systemd`
Yes, it did generate the system services after I ran `systemctl --user daemon-reload`. I also did a dry-run and no error were shown.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the systemd tag states: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Please delete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your containers don't *restart*, they just *start* at login time, **because they stop when you log out.** (Looking at system logs with `journalctl -b` will probably reveal this.)

You're using quadlet to generate *user* services, not system services (hence `systemctl --user`), and those are managed by a "user service manager" instance that automatically starts on user login and stops on logout.

Use `loginctl enable-linger $USER` to have your user service manager start on boot and remain running until system shutdown.

Comment: I just logged out from podman user and I tried to access one of the endpoint provided by one of the containers and I can access the webpage of such service.
So it doesn't seem containers stop when I log out.
I even logged back in and now the `CREATED` label reads `11 hours ago`.
But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I even checked with `journalctl -b` (I didn't know this command, thanks!) and I see containers operations log all afternoon long when I was not logged in.